# Remove rows where datetime is a specific day between specific times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am using this dataset:

https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/2c468679fa66c04c08a0ca624ca92d8f

What I want to achieve is:

1. Check the day is Monday or Friday
2. If so, remove the first 2 hours values from Monday and the last 2 hours values from Friday from the Dataframe in pandas

I have tried to load the values from the csv using the pandas dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("EURM1.csv")
```

But I don't know how to sort the data in the fashion I want. I tried using the `startdate` and `enddate`, but they are of no use to me.

Please help me to get the data in the form I want it.

Comment: Conver the date to `datetime` and then easily check what day it is with [`Series.dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html)

Comment: My date is in `datetime` format already. But the sample is on gist. Hence, it gives date in string format. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have converted the column to datetime, you can easily perform a conditional operation on it as per your logic:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

df = df.loc[~((df["date"].dt.weekday_name == "Monday") # Excludes Mondays before 2am
            & (df["date"].dt.hour < 2)) 

          & ~((df["date"].dt.weekday_name == "Friday") # Excludes Fridays after 10pm
            & (df["date"].dt.hour >= 22))]
```